Mockito I get NullPointerException when trying to access HashMap with getter
I have this Test class:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private Cache cache;
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Mock
    private CacheMap<Long, User> userCacheMap;
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void getUser() throws EntityNotFoundException {
        User user = new User(1,
                "Artem",
                "Shaputko",
                "a",
                "a@gmail.com",
                new ArrayList<>());
        userCacheMap = new CacheMap<>();
        Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(Mockito.eq(1L))).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));
        Mockito.when(cache.getUserCache()).thenReturn(userCacheMap);

        Assertions.assertThat(userService.findById(1L)).isEqualTo(Mapper.userToDTO(user));
    }

}

When I try to pass it I get this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.closer.citydistance.cache.CacheMap.get(Object)" because the return value of "com.closer.citydistance.cache.Cache.getUserCache()" is null
at com.closer.citydistance.service.UserService.findById(UserService.java:123)
at com.closer.citydistance.service.UserServiceTest.getUser(UserServiceTest.java:50)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)

Service`s method code:
@Validated
@Service
@Transactional
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final CityRepository cityRepository;
    private final Cache cache;
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND = "User not found";
    private static final String CITY_NOT_FOUND = "City not found";

    public UserDto findById(final Long userId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        User user = cache.getUserCache().get(userId);
        if (user != null) {
            return Mapper.userToDTO(user);
        }
        user = userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND));
        cache.getUserCache().put(userId, user);
        return Mapper.userToDTO(user);
    }

Cache class:
@Component
@Value
public class Cache {

    CacheMap<Long, User> userCache;
    CacheMap<Long, City> cityCache;
    CacheMap<Long, Sight> sightCache;

    public synchronized void removeUser(final Long id) {
        User user = userCache.get(id);
        if (user == null) {
            return;
        }
        user.getLikedCities()
                .forEach((City city) -> cityCache.remove(city.getId()));
    }

    public synchronized void removeCity(final Long id) {
        City city = cityCache.get(id);
        if (city == null) {
            return;
        }
        city.getUserLikes()
                .forEach((User user) -> userCache.remove(user.getId()));
        city.getSights()
                .forEach((Sight sight) -> sightCache.remove(sight.getId()));
    }

    public synchronized void removeSight(final Long id) {
        Sight sight = sightCache.get(id);
        if (sight == null) {
            return;
        }
        cityCache.remove(sight.getCity().getId());
    }
}

I tried to add mock-maker-inline to src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker but nothing changed

Can you show the rest of your UserService class please? Or at least, where cache object is instantiated

The reason is mixing SpringBootTest and MockitoExtension and their respective annotations (and probably wrong / incomplete constructor) - as a consequence object under test is improperly initialized. This is a frequently asked question, but I cannot see how this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232204/junit-force-to-throw-exception-on-method-call - voting to reopen
